# Why is the Serialization limit set to 0x02000000?

Tags: bitcoind, client, development, protocol

In addition to the block size limit, there is a limit on the maximum message size. Is there a rationale behind the 32MB limit set in `src/serialize.h` or was it picked because it's just a nice round number?